Octave can't find any folders
When I run very simple code, octave returns that the Folder does not exist, but I'm pretty sure it exists.
I can't grasp what I'm doing wrong.
function TestLoading(path)
    if isfolder(path)
        disp('Folder exists');
    else
        disp('Folder does not exist');
    end
end
folder_path = "C:/A";
TestLoading(folder_path);

I can't get it to find any folder. I can load some files from that directory, just isfolder not working.

What is you filename? In Octave and Matlab name of .m files matter.
I changed your code and added a simple disp command to it:
function TestLoading(path)
    if isfolder(path)
        disp('Folder exists');
    else
        disp('Folder does not exist');
    end
end

disp('Hello World');
folder_path = pwd();
TestLoading(folder_path);

By running octave TestLoading.m, you can be sure the Hello World won't be printed. Since Octave runs your TestLoading function, not its caller code (and all codes after it). So It will run with empty path argument and displays Folder does not exist.
I edited your code and saved in MyFunc.m file:
function MyFunc()
    folder_path = pwd();
    TestLoading(folder_path);
end

function TestLoading(path)
    if isfolder(path)
        disp('Folder exists');
    else
        disp('Folder does not exist');
    end
end

And running it:
[gmt@arch ~]$ octave MyFunc.m 
Folder exists


I'm running GUI, on Windows. But switched to CLI to test your answer. It seems my def function was wrong. The IF statement works, so that concludes my Function was written wrong.
Sorry for Your trouble and thanks for your patience for a novice.

It doesn't matter. I tested in Octave GUI too.

My function must be strangely wrong-defined, (don't know yet what is wrong with it) so it won't give me errors compiling just the IF statement would be not met.

Your function is OK. But if you have a function TestLoading in TestLoading.m and you run TestLoading(a_path);, octave run the function. But your codes after the function body will not run. You must re-organize your code like my proposed code, or call your function from outside of its .m file.
